It’s all Greek to me!
The answer to this puzzle is a 5 letter word. (this is a definitive list)

 1.    CHANNEL 
 2.    STOPPER 
 3.    MAGNET 
 4. JAR
 5. CEMENT JAR
 6. GINGER
 7.    ROOM

Hint

 I deliberately omitted a tag starting with M…

Stronger hint

 The previous title to this puzzle was NOTE the hidden WAY


Does the number of spaces matter, or is it just significant that those words are offset from the rest?

That’s for you to work out

I believe the 5 letter answer is

 MODES.

The hints point to this puzzle being about

 music  (M..., Notes)
 And the title "Greek" along with a count of 7 items suggests the seven modern modes of music adapted from the Greek scales.

They are:

 Ionian, Dorian, Phrygian, Lydian, Mixolydian, Aeolian, Locrian

The list forms a representation of these by way of

 phonetic word associations:
      CHANNEL: ION CHANNEL - "Ionian"
      STOPPER: DOOR STOPPER - "Dorian"
      MAGNET: FRIDGE MAGNET - "Phrygian"
   JAR: JAR LID - "Lydian"
   CEMENT JAR: CEMENT MIXER + JAR LID - "Mixolydian"
   GINGER: GINGER ALE - "Aeolian"
      ROOM: LOCKER ROOM - "Locrian"  (? not positive on this)

Together these are the

 7 Western music MODES!


Nice!! Good job!
